# file backed mmap with huge page?

Tags: linux, mmap, huge-pages

-> Linux - Debian - Ext4 - Kernel 6.1

##### Other discussions

other relevant questions:

- [this try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060678/huge-pages-for-memory-mapped-files-on-linux)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718419/writing-a-mmapped-file-using-a-huge-page-mapping)
- [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400853/how-to-open-and-use-huge-page-and-transparent-huge-page-in-code-on-ubuntu)
- [Debian's](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages)

##### My context

I currently use a mmap file ("/user_db/db.txt") that I share among multiple threads from a single app, for read/write access.

> Note: I need persistent storage for my DB.

**It works well**, even under chaos testing, the threads respect the locks when accessing memory regions and so on.

Now, I keep reading about huge page, to go a bit further. Especially the 1GB ones as my file spans on multiple GB already.
It would be great to have it enabled for my app.

##### Alternative thinking

But as I read it, what I am trying to achieve is not possible and certainly the wrong way to do it (or are there solutions as of 2023?).

I should instead use DIRECT_IO (meaning reading a 512bytes block, modifying the offsets with my data, and write back to disk), but that's too much, 512 bytes is too big and will create a greater contention for my access pattern. A cache line size is fine though.

The best option that could exist for me is a transparent huge page of size 1GB (I have 32GB+ RAM systems at hand for this single app).

Any modern options I missed? Thanks

Comment: All disk I/O uses the disk block size, which is usually 512 or 4096 bytees.

Comment: @stark: I see, so Direct_IO is the way to go then..